# How to get button on hover state to achieve linear gradient with border radius?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, hover, css-animations

I have a button that on hover has a linear gradient, from left to right, that also has the same border radius as the button itself (25%). What is the best way to achieve such a styling?

I have attached a picture of the animation occuring mid way through, to give a visualisation of what I mean.

Currently, I am using the backgroundImage with backgroundSize and on hover, changing the size to 0.

```
  backgroundPosition: '100% 0',
  backgroundSize: '300% 100%',
  backgroundImage:
    'linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, #95E7A4 10%, #8FD8FA 35%, #CBBEFA 66%, #FEFEFE 94%)',
  transition: 'all 1s ease-in-out',
```

```
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundPosition: '0 0',
    borderColor: theme.colors.black,
  }
```

[image]